# How to fix a security alert for a Google Cloud Platform API key?

Tags: android, api-key, google-play-console

I have uploaded an updated version of my application, and in the google play console, the following error appears:
 
"Security alert
Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys. For more information, see this article in the Google Help Center.
Vulnerable locations:
androidx.fragment.app.d-> m
It affects version 3 of the APK."

I've been searching on "androidx.fragment.app.d-> m" and I really can't find anything related to a Google Cloud Platform API. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys. Please see this Google Help Center article for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890238/your-app-contains-exposed-google-cloud-platform-gcp-api-keys-please-see-this)