# Cloud Vision - Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys

Tags: android, google-cloud-vision, android-security

I am using Cloud Vision API in my application where I have the API key in my code and I got this warning in the Google Play Console : **Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys**

So I used Jerjou's answer ( https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/pull/104/commits/431093c61a817df6ca88f7e644bc6219cd7aff05 )
to restrict the API key to my application and after I updated the application the warning went away but today the error came back.Any solutions to make it go away would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your app also have Google Play Ads? This GCP warning can also be triggered by their SDK (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57318428/4084269)

Comment: I do but the warning appeared because I have the Key in my code. I was forced to use this workaround (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56964127/7520147) just to make it disappear since I have restricted the key. Thanks for your time though